# Properties of ridge regression hat matrix and ridge residuals

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I'm referencing https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf on ridge regression. On page 34 question 1.5 we need to prove :

Ridge fit $\widehat{Y}(\lambda)=X(X^{\top}X+\lambda I_p)^{-1}X^{\top}Y$ is not orthogonal to ridge residual $Y − \widehat{Y}(\lambda)$.

To how this since I think we can use that the hat matrix for ridge regression is not a projection matrix but that does not give me anything useful. In the OLS case we show that the residual is not orthogonal to $X$ since $\widehat{Y}(\lambda)$ is linear combination of $X$, but I do not think we can use this here as the linear combination property might not hold here due to the term $\lambda I_p$. Please tell how to show this.